# how do I animate a vesicle fusing to a cell membrane?

Tags: animation

I am a medical educator and new to blender animatoin. I want to create a viral particle (UV sphere) "blending" into a cellular membrane. I will appreciate pointing me into the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add reference images of what you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

Could you add some reference images of the effect you are trying to achieve? It is not clear what you want to do.

Would it be something similar to what's illustrated bellow? You can easily create merging/blending soft shapes with meta geometries.

Just create two meta ball objects with<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Meta Ball*, scale them down accordingly, then adjust the properties as desired as the *Threshold* and *Resolution*. 
Move them around and their geometry should just fuse together naturally.

[image]